# Android: Minimize Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need for an activity to return to the previous activity but if click again on that button it resumes the activity where it was for the last time.
This is the desired process:
I click on a button and the activity starts. If I click on the Back button to return to the previous activity, but if the user clicks again the button the activity resumes to where it was for the last time.

I have tried with `onBackPressed(){moveTaskToBack(true)}`; but it just minimizes the whole application. Any suggestions?

Edit:Hi, sorry for the explanation. I mean that if in an activity the user selects back button, the activity is put in background and the previous ( not finished) activity is loaded. Then if I click on a specific button again the activity in background is resumed.

Thanks

Comment: This is way too confusing. Could you make another attempt at explaining the situation?

Comment: I'm Confused! Is there anyone like me? If not then please explain me what does this mean.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the explanation. I mean that if in an activity the user selects back button, the activity is put in background and the previous ( not finished) activity is loaded. Then if I click on a specific button again the activity in background is resumed.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me. Hope it works for you too:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
         {
            this.moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
         }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. However this code minimizes the whole application when I press the Back Button. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

This is be cause all your activities are part of the same task.  When calling moveTaskToBack(true), it will move the entire application to the back if they are all part of the same task.

To fix this, you would need to start the activity to be minimized in a separate task.